# Can a matrix have any characteristic polynomial?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ring-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

Given a polynomial $P(X) \in R[X]$ of degree $n$ over a ring $R$, does there *always* exist some matrix $A \in \mathrm{M}_{n \times n}(R)$ whose characteristic polynomial is $P(\lambda)$? i.e. $\det(A-\lambda I) = P(\lambda)$.

If not, are there conditions on $R$ which can guarantee the above? Is this true in the case where $R$ is one of the "standard" rings, e.g. $\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Search for ”companion matrix“ and you will find what you want. It is for monic polynomials though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To flesh out the comment a little bit more: by definition, the [characteristic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial) of a matrix $A$ equals $\det(xI-A)$ which is seen to be a monic polynomial, so the more interesting question is whether every *monic* polynomial $P(X)\in R[X]$ is a characteristic polynoimal of some matrix with coefficients in $R$. And the answer to this question is yes, with an explicit construction given by [the companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix).

This means that we associate to the polynomial $P(X)=X^n+c_{n-1}X^{n-1}+\cdots+c_0$ the matrix
$$A(c_0,c_1,\ldots,c_{n-1}):=
\begin{pmatrix}
0&\ldots &0&-c_0\\
1&\ldots &0&-c_1\\
\vdots&\ddots &\vdots&\vdots\\
0&\ldots &1&-c_{n-1}\\
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0&-c_0\\I_{n-1}&-c_{1:n-1}\end{pmatrix}
$$
with the coefficients $c_0,\ldots,c_{n-1}$ elements of $R$, where the rightmost expression is using a block matrix notation: $I_{n-1}$ is the $(n-1)\times (n-1)$ identity matrix, and $c_{1:n-1}$ is the column vector in $R^{n-1}$ with entries $(c_1,\ldots,c_{n-1})$.

Now we can compute the characteristic polynomial of $A(c_0,c_1,\ldots,c_{n-1})$ using [cofactor expansion](https://people.math.carleton.ca/~kcheung/math/notes/MATH1107/wk07/07_cofactor_expansion.html) along the top row, as follows (using $\operatorname{charp}$ to denote the characteristic polynomial of a matrix):

$$\begin{align*}
\operatorname{charp} A(c_0,c_1,\ldots,c_{n-1})&=\det\Bigl[X\ I_n-\begin{pmatrix}0&-c_0\\I_{n-1}&-c_{1:n-1}\end{pmatrix}\Bigr]\\
&=X\det\Bigl[X\ I_{n-1}-\begin{pmatrix}0&-c_1\\I_{n-2}&-c_{2:n-1}\end{pmatrix}\Bigr]+c_0\det I_{n-1}\\
&=X \operatorname{charp} A(c_1,\ldots,c_{n-1})+c_0.
\end{align*}
$$
Thus, it follows by induction on $n$ that $\operatorname{charp} A(c_0,c_1,\ldots,c_{n-1})=P(X)$.